# Cholesky decomposition for correlated variables

Tags: correlation, gaussian

I have been reading about how to use Choelesky decomposition to generate correlated variables given a correlation matrix. This question explains how to to achieve it [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160054/how-to-use-the-cholesky-decomposition-or-an-alternative-for-correlated-data-si).

What about if I want that x1 to be uncorrelated with x3? I have tried to specify the correlation matrix as

```
cor_matrix = np.array([[1.0, 0.6, 0],
                       [0.6, 1.0, 0.5],
                       [0  , 0.5, 1.0]])   The correlation matrix [3 x 3]
```

instead of the one in the example in the link, but I dont get uncorrelated x1 and x3 variables.